# Abrir um browser minimizado em Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, processo

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em Windows Forms e estou com o seguinte problema, quando o usuário clicar num botão do `form`, ele terá que maximizar uma página da internet que se encontra minimizada, ou seja, trazer a janela do browser para o primeiro plano e maximiza-la.

Só achei códigos que abrem uma nova página:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com/");
```

mas o intuito não seria esse.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta do SOen para ver se ajuda em algo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/878429/8133067

Answer (score 0):

Este é um problema muito específico. Pois visto que você pode passar alguns argumentos para a aplicação, é apenas o desenvolvedor do produto que decide o que é possível ou não ser feito com estes argumentos.

É meio complicado encontrar "gambiarras" que sejam realmente efetivas pra todos os navegadores possíveis, sendo necessário mais manutenção caso haja algum update ou algo do tipo na versão do programa de terceiros.

Mas no geral é possível checar o registro para encontrar o browser padrão, e então minimizar a janela existente veja [aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CWindow.aspx) mais detalhes.

Outro ponto importante é que o produto pode ser configurado pelo usuário para se comportar exatamente dessa maneira indesejada (abrir sempre maximizado) e, você substitui esse comportamento que o usuário configurou pode causar algumas reclamações.

Mas caso seja exatamente isso que você deseje, você pode utilizar o seguinte exemplo:

IE

```cs
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

Process.Start(startInfo);

startInfo.Arguments = "http://www.google.com";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Alvaro Alves agradeço a atenção mas talvez eu não tenha explicado direito, no código que vc mandou eu inicio um novo navegador minimizado. O objetivo na verdade é maximizar um navegador que estiver minizado e não abrir um novo...